dialog/transparent activity trans touch event to other window?
I want to create a dialog that contains a layout inside. This layout should be scrollable up and down. When the dialog is scrolled up to only show a drag handle, I want the dialog to pass all click events (except those on the drag handle) to the underlying window's application page. When the dialog is scrolled down, the dialog's content view should be able to handle click events. I found that only FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE can block click events for the current window. Is there any other way to pass the dialog's click events to other windows? My dialog does not rely on the context of an activity.
I tried transparnet activity and customized dialog ,but not effect

If this is all for your own app, do not use a dialog. Instead, have your scrollable content be part of the main window, just higher on the Z axis.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
